# Ionic file transfer too big?

Tags: node.js, express, ionic-framework, ionic3, multer

I have an ionic 3 app where I'm using the ionic native camera and file transfer plugins to take a picture and send to my Node.js/Express API to store the image files.

On my server, I'm using 'multer'.

Seems like everything is working, but when I try to upload the image, I get the following error:

```
2018-06-10 10:05:25.052951-0700 SynctupV3[3058:1625890] CDVWKWebViewEngine: handleStopScroll
2018-06-10 10:05:25.601142-0700 SynctupV3[3058:1626144] WriteStreamError domain: 0 error: 0
2018-06-10 10:05:25.605004-0700 SynctupV3[3058:1626399] File Transfer Finished with response code 413
2018-06-10 10:05:25.755113-0700 SynctupV3[3058:1626399] FileTransferError {
    body = "<html>
\n<head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>
\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">
\n<center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>
\n<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
\n</body>
\n</html>
```

My multer implementation is pretty simple:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest:'fileuploads/'});
var constants = require('./helpers/constants');

router.route
  .post('/', upload.any(),function(req, res, next){

  res.send(req.files);

})

module.exports = router;
```

This is what my file transfer looks like on the UI side:

```
  uploadImage(){
    let loader = this.loader.create({
      content: 'uploading...'
    });
    loader.present();

    const fileTransfer : FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: 'photo',
      fileName: 'myimage_' + random + '.jpg',
      chunkedMode: false,
      httpMethod: 'post',
      mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
      headers:{
        Connection: "close"
      }
    }

    fileTransfer.upload(this.myPhoto, this.globals.API_ENDPOINT + 'uploads', options)
      .then((data)=> {
        alert('Success');
        loader.dismiss();
      }, (err)=>{
        alert(err);
        loader.dismiss();
      })

  }
```

Can anyone suggest what I might look at?